# Jittery Vertical Scrolling using mousewheel.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll, mousewheel

So I'm using mousewheel.js to detect when the user scrolls anywhere on the document to manually scroll some div.

I'm doing this with this function:

```
$(document).bind('mousewheel', function(event, delta, deltaX, deltaY) 
{
    if(delta < 0)
    {
        $('#postscroller').scrollTop($('#postscroller').scrollTop() + 60);
    }
    else
    {
        $('#postscroller').scrollTop($('#postscroller').scrollTop() - 60);
    }
});
```

In my desktop it works great, but when I try it in a chromebook, that has horizontal scrolling on the touchpad, the vertical scrolling becomes jittery and if I scroll horizontally it will scroll vertically.

I've tried various workarounds like:

```
var delta = (Math.abs(deltaX)>Math.abs(deltaY)) ? (-1 * deltaX) : deltaY;
```

And tried to disable horizontal scrolling altogether like:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMMouseScroll', function(e) { 
if (e.axis == e.HORIZONTAL_AXIS) {
    e.stopPropagation(); 
    e.preventDefault();
    e.cancelBubble = false; 
}
return false;
}, false);
```

or

```
var $body = $(document);
$body.bind('scroll', function() {
    // "Disable" the horizontal scroll.
    if ($body.scrollLeft() !== 0) {
        $body.scrollLeft(0);
    }
});
```

Those didn't work. 
Any help on the matter is appreciated.